# Global objects or not?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have WinForms app and multiple forms and want to use `ErrorProvider` component on each of them **EDIT:** to check if user input is OK (for example if entered number is in the range etc...) It seems to me useless to drop this component onto each and every form. What if I make one *global object* (or how to call it) and use it on every form?

My idea:

```
namespace MyApplication {  
static class Program {  

public static ErrorProvider EP = new ErrorProvider();
...
```

And then in that individual form to handle `Validating` and `Validated` events:

```
private void txtBox1_Validating(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e) {
  if (txtBox1.Text != "correct text") {
    e.Cancel = true;
    Program.EP.SetError(txtBox1, "You have error in your input");
...
```

Is this correct approach or should I do it somehow else?

And if I need more *global objects*, maybe I should put them all together to some separate static class and in the `Program` create just this one (?)
Thanks.

Comment: What are you going to be using the `ErrorProvider` for? Will it be holding state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can create a new class that inherits textbox class and add your validations there, then create a new control which is your class and use it where ever you need, in this case you will edit/modify your validations in one place later on.

I f you have very different validations create 2 classes for example: NumericTextBox and StringTextBox

Answer (score 1):

This approach is valid as long as your individual forms are never running concurrently or your error provider is re-entrant, and your error provider does not need a permanent link back to your forms. From the example that you show it appears that your provider requires you to pass the control on which to set the error state, so it has a good chance of being re-entrant.

Answer (score 1):

It is ok to have global object but I would rather make it a static stateless class if possible. Statelessness will allow for easy thread safety. It is common across .NET to have global (within namespace) static classes, for example `FileInfo` or `Convert`.

If you only need a few global methods and they operate on UI elements you can also write some extension methods for `System.Windows.Controls.Control` or even `System.Windows.Controls.TextBox` if that's the only control you want. This will give you a bit nicer code:

```
txtBox1.Validate("correct text", "You have error in your input");
```

Extension method could look like this:

```
public static class MyExtension
{
    public static void Validate(this TextBox myTextBox, string correctText, string error)
    {
        if(myTextBox.Text != correctText)
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} [{1} == '{2}']", error, myTextBox.Name, myTextBox.Text));
    }
}
```

Which would give you this message in the console:

`You have error in your input [txtBox1 == 'some text']`

Look at extension methods [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) if you need more info.

Comment: @Enriqe, you can always change what you've selected as the best answer to your question :-)

Comment: :D Yeah, you are right. I like the idea of writing extension of some basic component, I know you wrote it too but @Ali Issa was first, anyway thanks for making my mood :) Have a nice day and.... sorry ;)